# Css errors in div

Tags: html, css, alignment

How to align `c` div on bottom of `a`?

`Position:relative` doesnt help.

[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/SD09hCF1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `#c` absolutely positioned, and `#a` relatively positioned:

```css
#a {
    width:250px; 
    height:250px; 
    background:grey;        
    position: relative;
}
#b { }
#c {
    bottom:0px; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://tinkerbin.com/oOPtfTR4)